# Optimal rule for multiple stopping times for defect finding

Tags: stochastic-processes, oc.optimization-and-control, combinatorial-optimization

Suppose a quality inspector is inspecting $b$ black amongst which $d_B$ are known to be defective and $w$ white gadgets amongst which $d_W$ are known to be defective. The gadgets come down along an assembly line one by one in uniformly distributed random order. As each gadget passes, the inspector observes its color, and he chooses to let the gadget pass or use a device to detect whether the gadget is defective. But he can only use the device a total of $n$ times. What is the optimal stopping rule to use the inspecting device to maximize the expected number of defective gadgets found.

---

**Edit:** As fedja points out below, there is a difference between detecting a defect by the device and deducing for sure by logic a defect. Both are legitimate objectives. The solution to the first is easier than that to the second. I for now choose the first definition, i.e., to define finding a defective gadget as only indicated by the device and use up one quota of using the device even if the quality inspector is sure by logic alone the gadget under inspection is defective.

---

Suppose at a pass the number of black gadgets already inspected by the device is $i_B$, amongst them $f_B$ are detected to be defective. Suppose the current passing gadget is black and yet to be inspected. Then the probability of this black gadget being defective is $p_B=\frac{d_B-f_B}{b-i_B}$. Symmetrical probability holds for if the current passing gadget is white.

I have a conjecture for the explicit solution, which is a greedy algorithm, as follows and am seeking a proof.

At a pass of the gadget, without loss of generality, suppose the current gadget which has not yet been inspected is black. Suppose there are $n_B$ black including the current one and $n_w$ white gadgets left. Suppose $i_B$ black and $i_W$ white gadgets have been inspected, amongst which $f_B$ black and $f_W$ have been found to be defective. If $p_B\ge p_W$ or $n_W=0$ the inspector inspect the current black gadget with the device. Otherwise, the inspector let the current black gadget pass without inspection.

I have set up the dynamic programming formulation but fail to see either the proof or a counterexample to my conjecture.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769463/optimal-rule-for-multiple-stopping-times-for-defect-finding)

Comment: @RobPratt: It is just that so far it does not look like I can get an answer there.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3769463/14578, https://mathoverflow.net/q/366646/37212, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47306/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  Please pick one.  You can delete the question elsewhere if you decide you've posted it on the wrong site.

Comment: @D.W.: I noted the cross posting on the computer science site. That was how you came here. Also, 5 days have lapsed since I posted this question here before I post the question on the computer science site. Let me add more details to the question to answer your questions.

Comment: Your condition $p_b<p_w$ does not include $n_b$ and $n_w$ in any way. On the other hand, it is clear that if $n_w=0$, then just passing all remaining black gadgets is suboptimal. Do I misunderstand something about the proposed greedy algorithm?

Comment: @fedja: You are right. I have edited my conjectured algorithm. Would you like to have a crack at the problem? Thank you.

Comment: The current model seems too complicated to make a reasonable exact answer possible: all sorts of issues arise (like if $d_w=n_w$, you don't need a single test to reject all white gadgets). Writing the full set of dynamic programming equations is possible, of course, but the variables would be full distributions, not mere expectations. However, if it comes from a real life problem, we can try to make a shot at an approximate solution. Then it will be very helpful to know what range of parameters you are thinking of.

Comment: @fedja: First, do you agree with my dynamic programming solution in my answer below?

Comment: If the objective is to maximize the number of beeps on the detector (i.e., if you ignore special cases like the one I mentioned), then the recursion looks correct. One also needs to set the boundary values though to make it a full set of equations.

Comment: @fedja: The objective is quite clear from the question which is "to maximize the expected number of defective gadgets found" which is equivalent to what you say except it should be the *expected* number of beeps. I neglected to put the boundary condition as I thought it was quite obvious. I can put it up for completeness. As for the special case like the one you mentioned where say $n_W=0$, it should be a corollary derived from the recursion along with the boundary condition rather than an independent case.

Comment: "*which is equivalent to what you say*" But, as I said earlier, it is not: if we have, say, 4 white and 4 black gadgets remaining with 3 tests left, and we know that all whites are defective and 1 out of 4 blacks is defective, then we maximize the expected number of beeps by testing the white gadgets and maximize the expected number of "found" (in the sense "proved to be defective by direct measurement or logical derivation") gadgets by testing blacks. Am I making sense? The objective can be formally set to be either one, I just asked which one you had in mind.

Comment: @fedja: Yes, you are making perfect sense. Actually, now I remember this case did occur to me when I was thinking about this problem. But I forgot about it when I wrote the recursion. It is the expected number of beeps I am asking in the question. I will make the statement more rigorous later. However, the second question of "proving to be defective by direct measurement or logical derivation" is a more interesting objective. It seems only the case when, at least one color, is all defective would make a difference. Am I missing something again?

Comment: @fedja: In that case, the recursion has a "discontinuity" in treating the cases and needs a special clause.It is somewhat discomforting.

Comment: *It seems only the case when, at least one color, is all defective would make a difference.* In the recursive formula, yes, but it changes the answer even in the cases when we haven't arrived at that situation yet but are potentially close to it. The "beep objective" results in a cleaner recursion and simpler boundary conditions, so let's stick to it for now: I still do not see how to finish even this case :-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not answer the ultimate question which is to prove or disprove the conjecture. But I hereby post the dynamic programming algorithm for solving any given set of parameters.

Let $\bigg(\begin{matrix}c_B&l_B&n_B \\c_W&l_W&n_W\end{matrix}\hspace{2ex} m\bigg)$ denote the maximal expected number of defects to be found with $n_B$ black and $n_W$ white gadgets to pass and $m$ inspections to use, where $c_B:=d_B-f_B$, $l_B:=b-i_B$, $c_W:=d_W-f_W$, $l_W:=b-i_W$. We obtain a recursion by conditioning on observing the color of the current passing gadget then taking the maximum of the expected maximum expectation of the defect detection based on maximizing the two choices of whether or not to use the device to detect the defect. At each pass of a gadget, the probability that the current gadget is black is $\frac{n_B}{n_B+n_W}$ while it is white is $\frac{n_W}{n_B+n_W}$. Conditioned on having observed the color of the passing gadget being black the probability of it being detected to be defective is $\frac{c_B}{l_B}$. Conditioned on having observed the color of the passing gadget being white the probability of it being detected to be defective is $\frac{c_W}{l_W}$.   We have the recursion
\begin{align}
    &\bigg(\begin{matrix}c_B&l_B&n_B \\c_W&l_W&n_W\end{matrix}\hspace{2ex} m\bigg) \nonumber \\[1ex]
    =&\ \ \frac{n_B}{n_B+n_W} \max 
        \begin{cases} 
        \frac{c_B}{l_B}\bigg(1+\bigg(\begin{matrix}c_B-1&l_B-1&n_B-1 \\c_W&l_W&n_W\end{matrix}\hspace{2ex} m-1\bigg) \bigg) +\Big(1-\frac{c_B}{l_B}\Big)\times \\ 
        \quad\quad\bigg(\begin{matrix}c_B&l_B-1&n_B-1 \\c_W&l_W&n_W\end{matrix}\hspace{2ex} m-1\bigg)  \\[4.5ex]
        \bigg(\begin{matrix}c_B&l_B&n_B-1 \\c_W&l_W&n_W\end{matrix}\hspace{2ex} m\bigg)
        \end{cases} \nonumber \\[2ex]
    &+ \frac{n_W}{n_B+n_W}\max 
        \begin{cases} 
        \frac{c_W}{l_W}\bigg(1+\bigg(\begin{matrix}c_B&l_B&n_B \\c_W-1&l_W-1&n_W-1\end{matrix}\hspace{2ex} m-1\bigg) \bigg) +\Big(1-\frac{c_W}{l_W}\Big)\times \\ 
        \quad\quad\bigg(\begin{matrix}c_B&l_B&n_B \\c_W&l_W-1&n_W-1\end{matrix}\hspace{2ex} m-1\bigg)  \\[4.5ex]
        \bigg(\begin{matrix}c_B&l_B&n_B \\c_W&l_W&n_W-1\end{matrix}\hspace{2ex} m\bigg)
        \end{cases} .
\end{align}